# Start/stop automatic rendering of navigator during dev

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, render

I develop with React and there are many manipulations on the code that are necessary to get progress worth seeing on the navigator, but each time a change is made on the code, the navigator refreshes and this becomes flashy and disturbing when you have both navigator and code windows opened side by side.

So, is there a way to lock/unlock renderings simply until I have finished what I am coding (new functionality, refactoring, etc.)?

I use VSC.